# Windows 7 BSoD + Restart when plugging and unplugging flash drive

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, usb-storage

I have a Gumstix Overo Fire COM that I have loaded with a basic linux kernel and mass storage drivers. The device is then connected to a host machine, to which it appears as a common USB storage device. It is then set up to repeatedly insert and remove its `g_file_storage` module every 5 seconds, to emulate repeated manual and insertion of the device into the host. While this may sound odd, it is entirely necessary, as I want to collect mass amounts of USB messages from the driver.

This repetitive "insertion" and "removal" of the device works fine on Mac and Linux hosts, but on most Windows machines, I get a BSoD after about 10 insertions and removals. Initially, I thought perhaps it was the device's "removal policy" that was causing the problem, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/179/why-does-unplugging-my-thumb-drive-result-in-a-blue-screen). However, some experimentation showed that this setting had no effect; the BSoD still showed up even when the removal policy was optimized for quick removal.

Also, I get no BSoD nor any errors on some Windows machines on which I have administrator control and which have all factory/default settings. The problem mostly occurs on public machines that are set up to have higher security and restricted user settings. Therefore, I believe it is some security setting that is causing the problem, but I am not familiar enough to know what exactly.

What sort of setting could be causing this problem?

**EDIT**: Here is the "Technical Information" on the BSoD:

```
*** STOP: 0x0000007E (0xFFFFFFFFC0000005, 0xFFFFF88001612652, 0xFFFFF88002FB9308, 0xFFFFF88002FB8B60)

*** FarSpace.sys - Address FFFFF88001612652 base at FFFFF88001600000, DateStamp 50046f1f
```

From what I can tell, the `Farspace.sys` is part of the [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/) software.

Comment: Unless you can provide us the BSOD information we can't even begin to guess whats causing this.  Set the system to the correct settings to GET this information.

Comment: upload the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump so that we can look at them with WinDbg.

Comment: @magicandre1981 So the machines this is happening on are the public machines I mentioned. They do not grant access to any System files and configurations, so I cannot access the MiniDump. EDIT: I WAS able to disable automatic reboot from the pre-boot advanced boot menu (haha!) so I can manually record the error info for you.

Comment: ok, uninstall or update this software

Comment: Unfortunately, the computers are public and I do not have permission to uninstall or update anything, let alone a software like Deep Freeze. I saw a way to disable/thaw Deep Freeze by messing with the CMOS, but I think that would be frowned upon by the lab staff. Is there any other way around this?

Answer (score 0):

A 7E stop error is "[SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)":

> This bug check indicates that a system thread generated an exception
>   that the error handler did not catch.

I'm pretty sure FarSpace.sys is part of Faronics' software, and they make [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/).  Since you say they are public machines, I'm guessing someone has them locked down with Deep Freeze, and that fact is making them not play nicely with your abnormal USB insertions/removals.

If that's the case, then first I'd test to see if they behave any differently while "thawed", and if so I'd then approach [Faronics' support](http://support.faronics.com/) from some guidance on doing what you want while the PC is "frozen".

Also, you may want to quadruple check any code you're using to ensure it's cleaning up it's threads properly when done with them.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown of the STOP error! I'm now looking into disabling/thawing DeepFreeze, but it looks like I don't have permission to do that, either! I have a feeling this error is caused by DeepFreeze and probably not my code, since the usb insertions are just being emulated by a shell script using `modprobe`.